Automated Windows 10 Recovery Reverted the Computer to the initial installation
sometime ago when I was working on my friend's old computer and I happen to install a fresh Windows 10 but after a driver installation the computer became unstable and I tried to rollback the driver installation but I coudn't find the the recovery method I used to ("Last known good configuration") so I started automated system recovery. But at the end of that recovery process the Windows reverted the computer state to my initial installation state without asking anything to me.
My question is; if there is a method to revert to computer to a specific system restoration point that I created using recovery console ?

Recovery Points is the name of the feature you are describing, however, it only effects system files not personal files so it has limited functionality

The best way to back up and to restore a PC to a specific state is to make a complete drive image. MS does not provide tools to do so, only to back up specific files. The PC manufacturer might provide restoration media to remove everything, and bring the PC back to the state when first bought. There are numerous drive imaging/cloning tools, some free, some not: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/five-free-and-reliable-cloning-tools/ , and https://www.techradar.com/best/best-disk-cloning-software , for example

Thank for your answers but one of the things that annoyed me is resetting the first installation state without asking approval. If I would know the whole OS reset to initial state I wouldn't confirm that and could try another approach.
